# Use git submodule foreach with function

Tags: bash, git

My indention is to have a script that updates all git submodules according to which branch is given. If there's no such branch for a submodule, master is used.

This is what I have now:

```
#!/bin/bash -x

if [ -z $1 ]; then
    echo "Branch name required."
    exit
fi

function pbranch {
    exists=`git show-ref refs/heads/$branch`

    if [ -z $exists ]; then
        branch="master"
    fi

    git co $branch
    git pull origin $branch
}

branch=$1

git submodule foreach pbranch
```

But when running this script, the error is thrown:

```
oleq@pc ~/project> git-fetchmodules major
+ '[' -z major ']'
+ branch=major
+ git submodule foreach pbranch
Entering 'submodule'
/usr/lib/git-core/git-submodule: 1: eval: pbranch: not found
Stopping at 'submodule'; script returned non-zero status.
```

My guess is that `git submodule foreach` utilizes eval (according to the [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-submodule.html)), which I don't use correctly in this context.

There are billions of [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030169/git-easy-way-pull-latest-of-all-submodules) of how to use this command with "inline callback" but I couldn't found a single one with the callback in form of the function. Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I resolved my issue by putting the function inside of the quotes as a callback:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z $1 ]; then
    echo "Branch name required."
    exit
fi

git submodule foreach "
    branch=$1;
    exists=\$(git show-ref refs/heads/\$branch | cut -d ' ' -f1);

    if [ -z \$exists ]; then
        branch='master';
    fi;

    echo Checking branch \$branch for submodule \$name.;

    git fetch --all -p;
    git co \$branch;
    git reset --hard origin/\$branch;
"
```

Note that variables like `$1` are those from the script's namespace. The "escaped ones" like `$\(bar)`, `\$branch` are evaluated within "the callback". It was pretty easy.

Comment: $variables in double quotes are replaced by bash with values but not when they are in single quote text. So, two solutions: 1) use double quotes and escape symbol `foreach " `\$variable` ... "`, or 2) use single quote without escape symbol like `foreach '... $branch ...'`

Answer (score 11):

You can use functions, but you need to export them first:

```
export -f pbranch
```

Also, if you want bash syntax extensions, you might want to force a bash shell to be started:

```
git submodule foreach bash -c 'pbranch'
```

Comment: Seems with bash 5.0.17 and git 2.25.1 this answer does not work, unfortunately...

Answer (score 6):

A shell function only exists inside the shell where it is defined. Similarly, a Java method only exists in the program instance where it is defined, and so on. You cannot invoke a shell function from another program, even if that program happens to be another shell that is run by a child process of the original shell.

Instead of defining a function, make `pbranch` a separate script. Put it in your PATH.

```
#!/bin/sh
branch="$1"
ref="$(git show-ref "refs/heads/$branch")"
if [ -z "$ref" ]; then
    branch="master"
fi
git co "$branch"
git pull origin "$branch"
```

Shell programming note: always put double quotes around variable substitutions and command substitutions: `"$foo"`, `"$(foo)"`, unless you know that you need to leave the quotes out. Unprotected substitutions are interpreted as whitespace-separated lists of glob patterns, which is almost never desired. Also, don't use backticks, for similar reasons, use `$(…)` instead. Here, it doesn't actually matter because git branch names don't contain special characters, and because `[ -z $branch ]` is parsed as `[ -z ]` which is also true when `branch` is empty. But don't get into the habit of omitting the quotes, it will come back and bite you.

Let's say the script is called `pbranch-submodule`, you can then run

```
git submodule foreach pbranch-submodule
```

Comment: And if you name it `git-pbranch-submodule`, it can behave like a built-in git command: `git pbranch-submodule` or `git submodule foreach git pbranch-submodule`. (Note that foreach accepts a shell command and not a git command.)